# Как реализовать функцию антифлуда в Aiogram

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram, бот

Имеется бот в телеграмме, бот отсылает запросы на сервер. Нужно как-то реализовать систему игнорирования пользователя в течении какого-то времени. Бот на аиограмме, слипы не подойдут.

```
@dp.message_handler(commands="parse")
async def parse(message: types.Message):
    data = message.text[len('/parse'):]
    count = data .split('\n')
    count = len(count)
    antik = count * 15 //тут я считаю сколько бот должен игнорировать юзера в секундах (в среднем на 1 запрос уходит порядка 15 секунд), например, если юзер отправит 3 заголовка для парсинга, то бот будет парсить эти заголовки где-то 45с, следовательно бот должен игнорировать его повторные попытки парсинга в течение 45ти секунд.
```

Как реализовать эту самую проверку?

Comment: 10 секунд в гугле: https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/examples/throtling_example.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from aiogram import types, Dispatcher
from aiogram.dispatcher.handler import CancelHandler, current_handler
from aiogram.dispatcher.middlewares import BaseMiddleware
from aiogram.types import Message
from aiogram.utils.exceptions import Throttled

from tgbot.data.config import get_admins

class ThrottlingMiddleware(BaseMiddleware):
    def __init__(self, limit=0.5, key_prefix='antiflood_'):
        self.rate_limit = limit
        self.prefix = key_prefix
        super(ThrottlingMiddleware, self).__init__()

    async def on_process_message(self, message: Message, data: dict):
        handler = current_handler.get()
        dispatcher = Dispatcher.get_current()

        if handler:
            limit = getattr(handler, "throttling_rate_limit", self.rate_limit)
            key = getattr(handler, "throttling_key", f"{self.prefix}_{handler.__name__}")
        else:
            limit = self.rate_limit
            key = f"{self.prefix}_message"

        if message.from_user.id not in get_admins():
            try:
                await dispatcher.throttle(key, rate=limit)
            except Throttled as t:
                await self.message_throttled(message, t)
                raise CancelHandler()

    @staticmethod
    async def message_throttled(message: types.Message, throttled: Throttled):
        if throttled.exceeded_count <= 2:
            await message.reply("спамить плохо")

def rate_limit(limit: int, key=None):
    def decorator(func):
        setattr(func, "throttling_rate_limit", limit)
        if key:
            setattr(func, "throttling_key", key)
        return func

    return decorator
```

Лучшее решение - мидлварь, он будет отлавливать любые сообщения пользователей и  в случае спама отменять хендлер.

```py
# подключаем их
def setup_middlewares(dp: Dispatcher):
    dp.middleware.setup(ThrottlingMiddleware())
    ....
```

Ну и теперь вызываем наш setup_middlewares при запуске.

Comment: Если где-то в каком-то хендлере нам нужно его отключить. Просто вешаем декоратор на хендлер
@rate_limit(0)

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл один вариант, код не мой, но он достаточно простой.

```
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor

bot = Bot(token='123:AbC')
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)


async def anti_flood(*args, **kwargs):
    m = args[0]
    #тут будет то, что нужно при флуде.
    await m.answer("Не флуди :)")


@dp.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
@dp.throttled(anti_flood, rate=1) #rate это количество секунд, при котором входящие сообщения считаются флудом.
async def main(m: types.Message):
    await m.answer(f"Вы отправили мне: {m.text} , я согласен с этим !")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, fast=True, skip_updates=True)
```

Помог чем смог, приятель.